# Why is my code getting this ValueError when it's automarked?

Tags: python

**So, my code is based of a module in a learning site which I use called Grok, these are the requirements which I had to create in order to pass to the next stage**

[The Requirements (left-hand-side of photo) and Auto Marker Error (bottom right handside)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggrKp.png)

*The error in question is;*

Testing a longer case with many letters. Your submission raised an exception of type ValueError. This occurred on line 4 of program.py.

I can't seem to figure out how to fix this to get it marked correctly, yet my code works pretty much perfectly.

**My code**

```
import collections
collect = collections.defaultdict(list)
order = input('Name: ')
name, surname = order.split(' ', 1)
collect[surname].append(name)

mail = open('mail.txt', encoding="UTF-8").read()
mail = mail.split('\n')
letter = 0
package = 0
count = mail.count(' '.join(collect[surname]) + ' ' + surname + ',Letter')
count2 = mail.count(' '.join(collect[surname]) + ' ' + surname + ',Package')

for i in collect:
  if (' '.join(collect[surname]) + ' ' + surname + ',Letter') in mail:
    letter += 1 * count
  if (' '.join(collect[surname]) + ' ' + surname + ',Package') in mail:
    package += 1 * count2

if package == 0 and letter == 0:
  print("No mail")

if letter > 1:
 print(count, "Letters")

if letter == 1:
 print(count, "Letter")

if letter == 0 and package != 0:
 print("No Letters")

if package > 1:
 print(count2, "Packages")

if package == 1:
  print(package, "Package")

if package == 0 and letter != 0:
  print("No Packages")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is only one space in the second line of the example for the third input in the screenshot.

Comment: Not sure I understand, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

For line 4 (`name, surname = order.split(' ', 1)`), the tuple unpacking will raise a ValueError if there's no space in `order`.

EDIT:

```
order = input('Name: ')

# was name, surname = order.split(' ', 1)
try:
    name, surname = order.split(' ', 1)
except ValueError:
    name, surname = order, ""

collect[surname].append(name)
```

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: Either don't unpack it (i.e., just work with `order`) or do something like `try: (original code) except ValueError: name, surname = (order, "")`.

Comment: Not sure I'm quite grasping. Mind editing my code to implement this?